# How to removal the Nothing type matched in case phase (scala)?

Tags: scala, match, case

During a function I use the simple code:

```
 match{
   case Some(one)=>one.copy()
   case Type =>
   ...
   case _ =>
}
```

There is error, since the Nothing is subtype of every type and Nothing do not have copy function.

AnyOne know how to delete the Nothing and Null Type matching in using match case phase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to note is that [no instances of `Nothing` ever exist](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.Nothing), and so you will never be in the situation where your match gets a value of `Nothing`.

That said, for the general case, the most obvious way is to simply provide cases for those first - cases are tested and executed in order, so adding them before the case the problem occurs at will result in the behavior you want:

```
??? match {
   case null => ???
   case Some(one) => one.copy()
   case Type =>
   ...
   case _ => ???
}
```

Obviously, the one of the main points of the `Option` type is to avoid the need for `null` checks. If you are ending up with a `null` in an `Option` variable, it's probably worth changing your code so that never happens.

Comment: Checking for `null` is not the same as checking for `Nothing`. If you wanted to check for `Nothing`, you'd need `_ : Nothing`, but, as you pointed out, that makes no sense. Either way it won't get rid of the OP's error.